# Proving that for all $x ∈ A$, $x$ is an upper bound of $B_1$ iff $x$ is an upper bound of $B_2$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification, relations

This is Velleman's exercise 4.4.18.a:

Suppose $R$ is a partial order on $A$, $B_1 ⊆ A$, $B_2 ⊆ A$, $∀x ∈ B_1∃y ∈ B_2(x Ry)$, and $∀x ∈ B_2∃y ∈ B_1(x Ry)$. Prove that for all $x ∈ A$, $x$ is an upper bound of $B_1$ iff $x$ is an upper bound of $B_2$.

Here's my proof of it:

Proof. Let $a$ be an arbitrary element of $A$.

($\rightarrow$) Suppose $∀x ∈ B_1(xRa)$ and let $x$ to be an arbitrary element of $B_2$. Since $x$ is an arbitrary element of $B_2$ then from $∀x ∈ B_2∃y ∈ B_1(x Ry)$ we get $∃y ∈ B_1(x Ry)$. Now we choose some $x_0$ such that $∃x_0 ∈ B_1(xRx_0)$. Now from $∃x_0 ∈ B_1$ and $∀x ∈ B_1(xRa)$ we get $x_0Ra$. Since $x$ was arbitrary then we'll have $xRa$. Therefore if $∀x ∈ B_1(xRa)$ then $∀x ∈ B_2(xRa)$.

($\leftarrow$) Similar to the proof of the forward direction.

From ($\rightarrow$) and ($\leftarrow$) we get $∀x ∈ B_1(xRa) \iff∀x ∈ B_2(xRa)$.

Is my proof correct?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is your proof true for all relations $R$, otherwise you might want to use some facts about it. Also, we don't choose some $x_0$ such that $\exists x_0.P(x_0)$ holds, given $\exists x.P(x)$ we choose some $x_0$ such that $P(x_0)$ holds. We also don't need that $x$ is an arbitrary element of $B_2$ to apply universal instantiation to $\forall x\in B_2(\dots)$, we just need that it is an element at all. (We do need that it is arbitrary to apply universal generalization later on.)

Comment: From the premise, show the lower set of B1 = the lower set of B2  and  use x is a upper bound of K iff x is an upper bound of the lower set of K.  The resulting proof will much less tedious.